# how to return a specified getter value when a value is entered into the console? - java

Tags: java, input

is their a way to return a method if the user inputs a method into the console? Currently i have a problem where i need the user to type the method name and then have the method occur, however due to how comeplex the methods are, it would have to be a massive if statement or mutliple arraylists to bring the answer back if there isnt an a way. Is there a way for the a system.in command to return not as a string or int, but in a way that the computer will read it as a normal call to a method?

Comment: There's the giant OOP way which is going to probably involve extending `Callable` and having a big `HashMap` (or factory) of them, etc ... and then there's reflection. Pick one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call method by name using [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful). As simple solution you can call method via reflection on every user request. As improvement, you can use reflection to build some kind of registry of methods at startup.

Comment: Yes he can - but it's bad practice!

Comment: @alfasin so do you have a better idea?

Comment: It's bad practice, if it's used everywhere. But in some simple cases it may be good solution.

Comment: Yes, the OO way: activate a selector method of the object with the string (user input) and have the selector choose the correct method and activate it. I understand that he's got a "massive if statement" but that may be due to a bad design. Need to see all the details in order to comment to that.

Comment: From Effective Java, Item53: Prefer interfaces to reflection "...As a rule, objects should not be accessed reflectively in normal applications at runtime." There are 3 good reasons why NOT to use reflection - I recommend on reading the book or at least this section before the next time you choose to use reflection :)

Comment: i appreciate what you are saying alfasin and i agree with you. But in this particular situation im having a hard time finding a way around it including rewriting the code,